# Angular 6.1 and IE11. sui-accordion-panel doesn't expand. Exception: Object doesn't support property or method 'animate'

Tags: angular, typescript, semantic-ui, ng2-semantic-ui

`<sui-accordion-panel>` should expand in IE11 but the `Object doesn't support property or method 'animate'` error appears instead, in the IE console window.

#### Steps

I added the `<sui-accordion>` with nested `<sui-accordion-panel>` to one of the views.
The code looks like follows:

```
//... other components 
  <div [hidden]="!isCreateNewFlag">
    <sui-accordion>
      <sui-accordion-panel [isOpen]="false">
        <div title>
          <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          <b>Additional options</b>       
        </div>
        <div content>
          <p>Upload initial answer file. (Select the template first.)</p>
          <app-file-uploader acceptedFormat=".anx" [isDisabled]="fileUploaderDisabled" [isFileValid]="isAnswerFileValid"
            (fileUploadedEvent)="onFileUploadedEvent($event)"></app-file-uploader>
        </div>
      </sui-accordion-panel>
    </sui-accordion>
  </div>

</app-form-modal>
```

The `<app-file-uploader>` which I created is not a problem here- even if I remove it from the above code I have the same problem with the accordion component.

#### Expected Result

The screenshot shows an expected behavior in the chrome web browser.
[image]

#### Actual Result

The expand thing doesn't work in the IE11:
[image]

#### Version

This is how my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "hd",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "generate-api-client": "call ../../Build/GenerateApiClient.bat",
    "predevbuild": "cpx ./src/styles/theme.config ./node_modules/semantic-ui-less/",
    "devbuild": "ng build --output-hashing none",
    "prebuild": "cpx ./src/styles/theme.config ./node_modules/semantic-ui-less/",
    "build": "ng build --prod --output-hashing none",
    "watch": "ng build --output-hashing none --watch",
    "test": "ng test --sourceMap=false --watch false",
    "test-watch": "ng test --sourceMap=false",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.7",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "date-fns": "1.29.0",
    "element-resize-detector": "1.1.14",
    "lodash-es": "4.17.10",
    "ng2-semantic-ui": "0.9.7",
    "rxjs": "6.2.1",
    "semantic-ui-calendar": "0.0.8",
    "semantic-ui-less": "2.3.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.7",
    "@types/element-resize-detector": "1.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.0",
    "@types/node": "10.5.3",
    "codelyzer": "4.4.2",
    "cpx": "1.5.0",
    "jasmine": "3.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "2.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "less": "2.7.3",
    "protractor": "5.3.2",
    "ts-node": "7.0.0",
    "tslint": "5.10.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea what can be wrong and is there any workaround to this issue?
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<sui-accordion>` is using `Web Animations API` that is not supported by all browsers. They tell  it at their docs here:

- https://edcarroll.github.io/ng2-semantic-ui/#/modules/accordion
- https://edcarroll.github.io/ng2-semantic-ui/#/modules/collapse

To solve this better in angular I suggest adding this to your `polyfill.ts` file (probably it is already there commented):

```
import 'web-animations-js';
```

To make that work you need to run: `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

**You can check the live example here:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-55650439?file=src%2Fpolyfills.ts